# about Swap tokens on Uniswap using a smart contract

Tags: uniswap, nodejs

I would like to build a bot (using VS code) that swaps ETH for other tokens and swap other tokens for ETH using a smart contract.I read the code in this article:https://cryptomarketpool.com/how-to-swap-tokens-on-uniswap-using-a-smart-contract/ There are several problems that have bothered me for a long time.
Question 1: how to transfer eth to the contract address My direct transfer eth will be returned
Question 2: how to authorize the contract to use the transferred eth
Does anyone here have any suggestions on how I can build this bot on VS code using nodejs or python and solidity?thank you
Code in Article:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;


//import the ERC20 interface

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}


//import the uniswap router
//the contract needs to use swapExactTokensForTokens
//this will allow us to import swapExactTokensForTokens into our contract

interface IUniswapV2Router {
  function getAmountsOut(uint256 amountIn, address[] memory path)
    external
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
  
  function swapExactTokensForTokens(
  
    //amount of tokens we are sending in
    uint256 amountIn,
    //the minimum amount of tokens we want out of the trade
    uint256 amountOutMin,
    //list of token addresses we are going to trade in.  this is necessary to calculate amounts
    address[] calldata path,
    //this is the address we are going to send the output tokens to
    address to,
    //the last time that the trade is valid for
    uint256 deadline
  ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Pair {
  function token0() external view returns (address);
  function token1() external view returns (address);
  function swap(
    uint256 amount0Out,
    uint256 amount1Out,
    address to,
    bytes calldata data
  ) external;
}

interface IUniswapV2Factory {
  function getPair(address token0, address token1) external returns (address);
}



contract tokenSwap {
    
    //address of the uniswap v2 router
    address private constant UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    
    //address of WETH token.  This is needed because some times it is better to trade through WETH.  
    //you might get a better price using WETH.  
    //example trading from token A to WETH then WETH to token B might result in a better price
    address private constant WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    

    //this swap function is used to trade from one token to another
    //the inputs are self explainatory
    //token in = the token address you want to trade out of
    //token out = the token address you want as the output of this trade
    //amount in = the amount of tokens you are sending in
    //amount out Min = the minimum amount of tokens you want out of the trade
    //to = the address you want the tokens to be sent to
    
   function swap(address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amountIn, uint256 _amountOutMin, address _to) external {
      
    //first we need to transfer the amount in tokens from the msg.sender to this contract
    //this contract will have the amount of in tokens
    IERC20(_tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountIn);
    
    //next we need to allow the uniswapv2 router to spend the token we just sent to this contract
    //by calling IERC20 approve you allow the uniswap contract to spend the tokens in this contract 
    IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, _amountIn);

    //path is an array of addresses.
    //this path array will have 3 addresses [tokenIn, WETH, tokenOut]
    //the if statement below takes into account if token in or token out is WETH.  then the path is only 2 addresses
    address[] memory path;
    if (_tokenIn == WETH || _tokenOut == WETH) {
      path = new address[](2);
      path[0] = _tokenIn;
      path[1] = _tokenOut;
    } else {
      path = new address[](3);
      path[0] = _tokenIn;
      path[1] = WETH;
      path[2] = _tokenOut;
    }
        //then we will call swapExactTokensForTokens
        //for the deadline we will pass in block.timestamp
        //the deadline is the latest time the trade is valid for
        IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amountIn, _amountOutMin, path, _to, block.timestamp);
    }
    
       //this function will return the minimum amount from a swap
       //input the 3 parameters below and it will return the minimum amount out
       //this is needed for the swap function above
     function getAmountOutMin(address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amountIn) external view returns (uint256) {

       //path is an array of addresses.
       //this path array will have 3 addresses [tokenIn, WETH, tokenOut]
       //the if statement below takes into account if token in or token out is WETH.  then the path is only 2 addresses
        address[] memory path;
        if (_tokenIn == WETH || _tokenOut == WETH) {
            path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = _tokenOut;
        } else {
            path = new address[](3);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = WETH;
            path[2] = _tokenOut;
        }
        
        uint256[] memory amountOutMins = IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).getAmountsOut(_amountIn, path);
        return amountOutMins[path.length -1];  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In solidity 0.6.0 and above, you can use the following code to enable the contract to receive ETH.

```
receive() external payable {}
```

In lower versions of solidity, the following code can be used to receive ETH

```
function () external payable {}
```

For native tokens on a chain (like ETH on Ethereum or BNB on BSC), you can create a function in the contract to transfer ETH without approve. :)